# How to resolve this Beamer error in TexStudio?

Tags: latex, beamer, texstudio

I have imported in TeXStudio a document that compile correctly on Overleaf.
But I got this error :

```
! Emergency stop.
\pgfsys@defineimage ...astform }\else {\pdfximage 
                                                  \pgf@imageheight \pgf@imag...
l.16 ...ight=12pt]{beamericonbook}{beamericonbook}
```

Anybody have an idea of the problem ?

[image: Screenshot]

TEX file content :

```
% Inbuilt themes in beamer
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{natbib}

% Theme choice:
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    }{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{macouleur}{RGB}{0,150,200}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=macouleur}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}

% Title page details: 
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\title{Génie Logiciel \newline ------ \newline
Introductions} 
\author{2022/2023}
\institute{Yo}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{withoutheadline}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.30]{Polytech.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}
\begin{withoutheadline}
\begin{frame}{Organisation du module}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 22h de CM/TD/TP
        \newline
        \item Programmation orientée Objet et UML
        \item Versionning et GIT
        \item Testing et Junit
        \item Design patterns et Java
        \newline
        \item Examen final sur table
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}
\begin{withoutheadline}
\begin{frame}{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}


\section{Logiciel, crise et génie logiciels}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1.1}

This is an unordered list:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

and this is an ordered list:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}


% Blocks frame
\section{Partie 2}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2.1}
    \begin{block}{Standard Block}
        This is a standard block.
    \end{block}
    \begin{alertblock}{Alert Message}
        This block presents alert message.
    \end{alertblock}
    \begin{exampleblock}{An example of typesetting tool}
        Example: MS Word, \LaTeX{}
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Log file :

```
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks39
\thm@bodyfont=\toks40
\thm@headfont=\toks41
\thm@notefont=\toks42
\thm@headpunct=\toks43
\thm@preskip=\skip61
\thm@postskip=\skip62
\thm@headsep=\skip63
\dth@everypar=\toks44
)
\c@theorem=\count333
)
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasethemes.st
y))
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerthemedefault.
sty
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerfontthemedefa
ult.sty)
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamercolorthemedef
ault.sty)
(C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerinnerthemedef
ault.sty
! I can't write on file `1.pdf'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-C to exit; default file extension is `.pdf')
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
\pgfsys@defineimage ...astform }\else {\pdfximage 
                                                  \pgf@imageheight \pgf@imag...
l.16 ...ight=12pt]{beamericonbook}{beamericonbook}
                                                  
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] and show your .log file

Comment: i have added the contents of the tex file and an the end of the log file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I can confirm that the tex file as such works fine. Can you please add the complete .log file? I'd like to see which engine you sue and the location of your tex file.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/026cac0bc63d4e7159002e25d5bcf90220221016171729/fd288f72c6ca6fcf52947967f042580120221016171744/a3187c

Comment: Your packages etc. look up-to-date. Two things to test: Is the pdf file open in some viewer like adobe reader? If yes close it before compiling. Do you have access rights to the location of the .tex file? Try to make a copy to a different folder. In particular check that the folder isn't some synced folder with dropbox or similar services.

Comment: indeed, I moved the file to another directory and the compilation works.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! And keep having fun with beamer :)